# onBlur Event on multiple textfields

Tags: php, javascript

I am creating a web form and inorder to validate the text fields am using **onblur event**. But what happens is if I leave a textfield empty and go to other a message box appears and when i try to go back to previous one onblur event of the second one is triggered and it goes like an infinite loop. And i cannot use *document.form.write*.
Is there any other way,using javascript,to print error message?

Answer (score 1):

It will be easy if you use jQuery for this.

```
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() 
     ...
});
```

Pure javascript way would be something like

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    inputs[i].onblur = functionHandler;

// Common function
function functionHandler() {
    if(this.value == "") { //get the value of tb triggering the event
        alert('empty'); //show the message
    }        
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/C2XBt/)

Comment: OP is already using onblur - why would doing so via jQuery fix the problem?

Comment: @nnnnnn, because its easy to attach to multiple text boxes

Answer (score 1):

Quick (but inelegant) fix: you could modify your existing code to use `onchange` instead of `onblur` - then it should trigger the event (and message) only if the content actually changed while it had focus, so if you click back and forth between fields without changing anything your validation won't keep getting triggered.

A better solution is to do something that doesn't pop up a message, but displays it as part of the page. One approach is to use JS to simply change the background colour of the field if it is invalid, and then on submit popup a single message listing all of the outstanding errors.